# Working with Object Array and inserting into the database - PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am studying some way to insert some information into the database and retrieve the ID, so that this ID is inserted into another table.

I need to know if this is possible, so as not to waste time on something if it was not possible to do:

Considering the array below:

```html
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 0
        [atraso_inicial] => 1
        [atraso_final] => 30
        [multa] => 2.00
        [juros] => 1.00
        [honorario] => 0.00
        [plano] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 0
                        [parcela] => 1
                        [ajuste] => 0.00
                        [entrada_minima] => 0.00
                        [desconto_multa] => 0.00
                        [desconto_juros] => 0.00
                        [desconto_principal] => 0.00
                        [desconto_honorario] => 0.00
                        [fase_id] => 1
                        [crud] => C
                    )

            )

        [campanha_id] => 1
        [crud] => C
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 0
        [atraso_inicial] => 31
        [atraso_final] => 60
        [multa] => 2.00
        [juros] => 1.00
        [honorario] => 0.00
        [plano] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 0
                        [parcela] => 1
                        [ajuste] => 0.00
                        [entrada_minima] => 0.00
                        [desconto_multa] => 0.00
                        [desconto_juros] => 0.00
                        [desconto_principal] => 0.00
                        [desconto_honorario] => 0.00
                        [fase_id] => 1
                        [crud] => C
                    )

            )

        [campanha_id] => 1
        [crud] => C
    )
)
```

I need to define in the [phase_id] item of the [plan] object, the value of the id of the key [0], and do the same thing with the key [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eBR4.png), and so on.

If I had the value of [id], before inserting, it would be easy, the problem is that at this point, I'm going to enter the data for the first time, so I do not have the ID yet.

What I have so far is the following controller and modal:

**controller**

```html
if (!empty($campanha[0]))
{
    $campanha_id = $this->empresa->add_campanha($campanha, $empresa_id);

    foreach ($campanha as $camp => $objeto_campanha)
    {
          $fase = $objeto_campanha->fase;
          $this->empresa->add_fase($fase, $campanha_id);
          foreach ($fase as $fas => $objeto_fase)
          {
               $plano = $objeto_fase->plano;
               $this->empresa->add_plano($plano);
           }
     }
}
```

**model**

```html
// add_campanha
public function add_campanha($dados, $empresa_id)
{       
    $array = (array) $dados;
    foreach ($dados as $camp)
    {
        $campanha = [       
            'nome'       => $camp->nome_campanha,
            'empresa_id' => $empresa_id,
        ];
        $this->db->insert($this->tb_campanha, $campanha);
        $campanha_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $campanha_id;
    }
}

// add_fase
public function add_fase($dados, $campanha_id)
{
    print_r($dados);
    $array = (array) $dados;
    foreach ($dados as $fase)
    {
        $fase = [
            'atraso_inicial' => $fase->atraso_inicial,
            'atraso_final'   => $fase->atraso_final,
            'multa'          => $fase->multa,
            'juros'          => $fase->juros,
            'honorario'      => $fase->honorario,
            'campanha_id'    => $campanha_id
        ];
        $this->db->insert($this->tb_fase, $fase);
        $fase_id = $this->db->insert_id();          
        return $fase_id;
    }
}

// add_plano
public function add_plano($dados)
{
    $array = (array) $dados;
    foreach ($dados as $plan)
    {
        $plano = [
            'parcela'            => $plan->parcela,
            'ajuste'             => $plan->ajuste,
            'entrada_minima'     => $plan->entrada_minima,
            'desconto_juros'     => $plan->desconto_juros,
            'desconto_multa'     => $plan->desconto_multa,
            'desconto_principal' => $plan->desconto_principal,
            'desconto_honorario' => $plan->desconto_honorario,
            'fase_id'            => $plan->fase_id,
        ];
        $this->db->insert($this->tb_plano, $plano);
    }
}
```

**table**

```html
/* campanha */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tb_campanha`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_campanha` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `empresa_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

/* fase */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tb_fase`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_fase` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `atraso_inicial` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `atraso_final` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `multa` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `juros` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `honorario` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `campanha_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

/* plano */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tb_plano`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_plano` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parcela` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ajuste` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `entrada_minima` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `desconto_juros` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `desconto_multa` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `desconto_principal` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `desconto_honorario` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `fase_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function add_fase() returns the $fase_id.  If I understand you correctly, you should put the following in your controller:

```html
  if (!empty($campanha[0]))
  {
      $campanha_id = $this->empresa->add_campanha($campanha, $empresa_id);

      foreach ($campanha as $camp => $objeto_campanha)
      {
            $fase = $objeto_campanha->fase;
            $fase_id = $this->empresa->add_fase($fase, $campanha_id);
            foreach ($fase as $fas => $objeto_fase)
            {
                 $plano = $objeto_fase->plano;
                 $this->empresa->add_plano($plano, $fase_id);
             }
       }
  }
```

And you would update your add_plano() model method like so:

```html
  public function add_plano($dados, $fase_id)
{
    $array = (array) $dados;
    foreach ($dados as $plan)
    {
        $plano = [
            'parcela'            => $plan->parcela,
            'ajuste'             => $plan->ajuste,
            'entrada_minima'     => $plan->entrada_minima,
            'desconto_juros'     => $plan->desconto_juros,
            'desconto_multa'     => $plan->desconto_multa,
            'desconto_principal' => $plan->desconto_principal,
            'desconto_honorario' => $plan->desconto_honorario,
            'fase_id'            => $fase_id, //note we've changed this to the fase_id that we explicitly passed as variable to this method
        ];
        $this->db->insert($this->tb_plano, $plano);
    }
}
```